# Why "preocupa" doesn't use "estoy"?

Tags: gramática

In Michel Thomas Spanish Masterclass, it says the following:

```
Estoy enfadado/enfadada  – I’m angry / annoyed
Estoy furioso / furiosa – I’m furious
Me preocupa mucho – I’m very worried (much)
```

Why does `preocupa` use `me` instead of `Estoy`. Is it a special case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a special case. It is just the way they created the example
You could also say:

> Estoy muy preocupado/preocupada

It depends if the subject is the situation or you.

and similarly you could change the other sentences like this.

> Me enfada mucho (esta situación) - Estoy enfadado por la situación
>
> Me enfurece (esta situación) - Estoy furioso por esta situación)

Comment: So does using estoy vs Me add a subtle difference to the meaning at all?

Comment: It's exactly the same in English. It is like saying "I'm angry" or saying "It angers me". In both cases I'm not so happy, but in the first sentence I'm talking about my current state and in the second I'm talking about what the situation makes me feel. Same with "I'm worried" or "This worries me"

Answer (score 1):

To add some more grammar to DGaleano's answer,

In your first example, the word "enfadado (angered)" is the past participle of "enfadar (to anger)". The past participle can be used to turn a verb into an adjective. In English, we usually add an "ed" to the end to form this verb form. In Spanish, they add either an "ado", or an "ido" (with a few irregular forms). Past participle adjectives take either "ser" or "estar" according to the usage of those verbs.

In the second example, there is no verb. Furioso (as with other ~oso words) is simply an adjective meaning furious. If you wanted to use a verb like in the third example, you could say "Me pone furioso/a", where "pone" is from the verb "poner".

In the third example, the verb in question is "preocupar (to worry)". You could say "estoy preocupado/a", meaning literally "I am worried". However, the example instead used the verb by saying "Me preocupa mucho", which literally means "[It] worries me a lot". The word "me" is the pronoun indicating the indirect object of the verb, or who is angered rather than what/who is doing the angering. This is the same thing that is happening when you say "Me gusta ([It] pleases me)", etc.